# KeyError: 'project' on Submitting JIra Ticket through Python

Tags: python, jira

I'm trying to automate the generation of Jira tickets using Python.  Running my script, I keep getting a traceback.

I'm running this on Ubuntu Linux with both Python 3.6 and 3.7 (my IDE points to 3.7).  I have searched the Web extensively for solutions, finding none.

```
def ticketBody(sprint, uid, [[other stuff]]):
    return({
        "fields": {
           "project": {"key": "DEV"},
           "summary": "Search Term: " + uid,
           "description": "Some Description",
           "issuetype": {"name": "Bug"},
           "Epic Link": "DEV-1",
           "Sprint": sprint,
           "assignee": "awesomeEngr",
        }
    })

BODY = ticketBody(sprint,uid,[other_params])
authd.create_issue(fields=BODY)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wsherwin/.../python/dataQuality.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/wsherwin/.../python/dataQuality.py", line 63, in main
    authd.create_issue(fields=BODY)
  File "/home/wsherwin/python-test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1095, in create_issue
    p = data['fields']['project']
KeyError: 'project'
```

The authd object takes the place of a jira object, and I cannot figure out why python/Jira can't find my project, because I've passed it along.

I would expect to have this return 0 with a successful conclusion - and a bunch of tickets filed.

Comment: I tried changing the return value from a dictionary; removing the parentheses still caused the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think your `createBody` function should only return the fields, not a dictionary with a single entry "fields":

```py
def ticketBody(sprint, uid):
    return {
        "project": {"key": "DEV"},
        "summary": "Search Term: " + uid,
        "description": "Some Description",
        "issuetype": {"name": "Bug"},
        "Epic Link": "DEV-1",
        "Sprint": sprint,
        "assignee": "awesomeEngr",
    }
```

*note:* You ought to follow the [PEP8 style guide](https://pep8.org/) and rename "ticketBody" in "ticket_body".